# SQL Server: save formulas in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, calculated-columns

is there a way to save formulas like the following in an SQL table ?

```
-- first Monday in @month of current year
dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, dateadd(m, @month-1, 
  dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, getdate()), 6)))/7*7, 0),
-- last Monday in @month of current year
dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, dateadd(m, @month, 
  dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, getdate()), 6)))/7*7, -7),
-- third Friday in @month of current year
dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, dateadd(m, @month-1, 
  dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, getdate()), 3)))/7*7, 18)
```

I have a table with a number of countries and need to save variable dates for each of them like in the below examples. 
These dates are simple date calculations, e.g. always the first Monday in May etc.
So I am trying to find the best way to handle something like this where the date values change every year - needed for 5 to 10 dates for each of around 30 countries.

I am pretty new to SQL so this is more about to find out options to handle something like this.

Many thanks for any help and suggestions on this, Mike.

Comment: Are you trying to store the formulas as text and then execute them later?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're looking for but you may want to look into creating a `view` http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: Andy: Yes, thats what I was hoping. I just updated my post as this is more to understand what options there are to handle something like this. Ideally I would like to avoid having a list of 30 case statements in a stored procedure or in PHP on my page so I am trying to sort it this way.

Comment: I think 30 CASE statements in your Stored Procedure is a better option than saving this functions in your database as strings

Comment: @M.Ali: Thanks. So this would be something like a Switch statement in PHP ? Does this exist in SQL ? Would there be any (performance) concerns if my list increases to 50 or more ?

Comment: Greg: This sounds exactly like what I was looking for. Can you provide me some more details on this ? What is the difference between a View and a temp table ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.  A view is definitely one thing you can do.  However, I think a computed column is a better approach (the documentation is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).

In SQL Server, you can put a calculation direction into a table definition.  One way is in the `create table` statement.  Another is using `alter table`:

```
alter table add FirstMondayOfCurrentYear as
    dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, dateadd(m, @month-1, dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, getdate()), 6)))/7*7, 0);
```

You will need to figure out what `@month` refers to.  The definition cannot use variables -- but you can definitely get the first monday of the current year without resorting to variables.

You can add as many as you like (okay, there is probably some limit, but I don't think you will hit it).

One very powerful feature of computed columns is that you can build indexes on them, and these indexes are maintained as the data changes over time.  Very convenient.

Do note that they are calculated when being used, so this might introduce some additional overhead.  That is generally a small price to pay.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gordon - this is very helpful ! To undertand this right, say I need 30 different dates calculated this way, does this mean I would need to add 30 columns or could I store different formulas in the same column ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).  It lets you take dynamic SQL strings -- including parameters! -- and execute them.  It's a bit sluggish compared to pre-compiled SQL statements, but if you're not looking for speed, it'll certainly give you the flexibility you want.